# BlogEngine.Net Code Formatting Extension that works?

Tags: blogengine.net

For months now I've been trying to find a code syntax formatting extension that works for BlogEngine.Net.  I'm not fond of the behavior of the default formatting extension, and have tried a couple of others (manoli is among them), but they always seem to interact badly with the TinyMCE editor.  Does anyone know of an extension that works, or a different approach that will allow me to make code samples pretty on my blog without hacking the crap out of the HTML myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, Rafe.  Thanks to [this post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BestCodeSyntaxHighlighterForSnippetsInYourBlog.aspx) that Hanselman put up the day after I asked the question, I downloaded WLW and am now using it.  As far as getting prettily formatted code, I'm using cut-and-paste from a little tool developed and available on [manoli.net](http://manoli.net/csharpformat/).

Answer (score 4):

I would try using Windows Live Writer along w/ the Paste From Visual Studio plugin. One you go WLW, you'll never go back to that damn TinyMCE interface.

WLW here:
http://get.live.com/writer/overview

Plugin here:
http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=d8835a5e-28da-4242-82eb-e1a006b083b9&l=8

Answer (score 0):

Check out SyntaxHighlighter..  Works excellent.  For easy integration into BlogEngine have a look at [my blog post](http://www.dscoduc.com/post/2008/09/25/More-Efficient-SyntaxHighlighter.aspx).